# Google Cloud VM request is missing authentication credential

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I recently deployed a Node.js/express application to a Google Cloud Compute VM. How do I send it get requests? I followed the instructions in [this](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/api/how-tos/api-requests-responses#python) article to get my URL. When I `curl` it from the command line, though, I get a 401 authentication credential error.

Request:

```
https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/*PROJECT_ID*/zones/*ZONE*/machineTypes/e2-standard-2
```

I am already logged into the gcloud SDK--is there some kind of other auth I need to network with my VM?

Full Error Message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Login Required.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "required",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "CREDENTIALS_MISSING",
        "domain": "googleapis.com",
        "metadata": {
          "method": "compute.v1.MachineTypesService.Get",
          "service": "compute.googleapis.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Your question shows an error without showing the code and the request. From the error message, it looks like you are calling the Compute Engine API. That API is used to manage Compute Engine resources and not to send GET requests to your application. Intead use the IP address of the VM instance.

Comment: See updated post for my request

Comment: your update did not help. What are you trying to accomplish? Read up on how OAuth works in Google Cloud. https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication

Comment: I think your comment about the IP address makes sense. I'm definately not trying to manage resources. I'm trying to get request my node.js / express process running on the VM

Comment: Look up the public IP address assigned to your VM instance in the Google Cloud Console GUI. Then use something like **curl http://vm-ip-address/** just like you would to any website.

Comment: What kind of configuration do I need to do on my vm before this will work? My `curl` connection was refused.

Comment: Your question has few details on what you have created or what you have configured. Read the documentation first before deploying a service. Hint: you probably did not set up the VPC firewall to allow HTTP. However, there are a lot of details to deploying an application on Compute Engine. Apache/Nginx, language, framework, file permissions, etc. Search Google Cloud and start with a tutorial.

Comment: How are you authenticating? One of the easy way is through [Access token](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#applications)